# convert rss to JSON

Tags: json, rss

craigslist has an rss feed and i wish to convert the feed to JSON format so that I can parse it. anybody know any tool that can do this - convert craigslist rss (or any rss) to JSON format

Answer (score 43):

**UPDATE**: beware, Yahoo Pipes has now been shutdown by Yahoo! and the Google Feed API has been deprecated. Check [superfeedr.com](http://superfeedr.com/)'s API which also does RSS to JSON conversion.

You can use google feed api service

Example:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=http://phys.org/rss-feed/&num=20
```

Structure https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=RSS_URL_TO_CONVERT&num=

Also if you want better control on RSS conversion use http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ where you can visualize data flow.

EDIT:
As yahoo pipes is no more working, here are the list of alternatives
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/12-best-yahoo-pipes-alternatives-look/

Comment: exactly what i looked for when Google referenced me to this answer :)

Comment: Google Feed API is dead with 2nd December 2015 :(

Answer (score 3):

RSS is already in XML format, which is natively parsable by all browsers.  I would recommend just parsing the XML directly instead of converting to json for parsing.

Comment: Web browsers wont let you download xml, they check the mime type, in a browser without lots of issues, otherwise I would agree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800769/how-do-i-pull-rss-feeds-into-jquery-tabs

Answer (score 2):

John Resig has a post about this:

http://ejohn.org/projects/rss2json/

Comment: tried this already. the example he gave on the page is not working. also tried using the url he supplied with craigslist, it's not working too

Comment: for example, i tried this - http://ejohn.org/apps/rss2json/?url=http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa/pen?query=&minAsk=1500&maxAsk=2000&bedrooms=2&neighborhood=&format=rss
and i didn't get any result

Comment: You downloaded the Perl scripts and followed all those directions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Yahoo Pipes to do this. You can simply pull the feed, and it acts as a proxy; JSONP is supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one of the many javascript libraries to navigate through the XML.

For example, [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery). There are many more libraries, [here are the ones](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#AjaxLibraries) Google thought were good enough to host.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the Oxygen XML Editor (http://www.oxygenxml.com/). They offer a 30-day trial version and it's cross-platform. You can find the converter under *Tools* -> *XML to JSON*...