# How do I pull rss feeds into jQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss

I want to set up some tabbed content on my site using jQuery and I want the tabs to pull the rss feeds from another part of the site. It's still the same site, though. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XML documents are on the *same* domain as your document it can be done with [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls, or you can use jQuery plugins to fetch *and* parse data with [jQuery RSS plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rss).

If they are on a *different* domain you can use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) to transform the remote XMLs to JSONP response which will work with all browsers, or you can use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) (cross domain AJAX) with the new ones.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the rss feeds are from the same website. I made a mistake in the original post. Is your answer still applicable?

Answer (score 3):

You cant pull cross domain contents. You may use JsonP if the data is available in that format. You can use Yahoo YQL to create a JsonP representation for the rss feed and then call that as yql query using jquery's ajax method.
Here is sample yql to convert the rss feed to json format

`yql = select * from  rss where url ="<feed url>"`

and you can use the following url as parameter to ajax/json function in jquery

`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=yql&format=json&callback=rssLoaded`

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's on the same domain. Not cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the information, and output it in a different way this should be done through PHP with the use of something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: It's just blog postings that I want to have feed into the tabs. I don't want it to output it another way. Do I still need to follow your suggestion?

Comment: If you would want to get information from a different site, you would have to use something like cURL yes. But if it's on your own domain, that changes everything and it's best to use AJAX like KARASZI István said.